# Unable to delete resource group in azure free trail

Tags: azure

I have a free azure a/c which is less than a month. I had created some resources (vnet, public ip, two vms )under one resource group rg-lab. I am unable to clean up the resource group. Not able to delete. Through some error resource is used my one VM but that VM does not exist. Please help to delete the resource group.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgX5X.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are still some of the resources exists in this resources group you are trying to delete. Go to Azure Portal and search "All resources" and select 'Clear Filter/Show Hidden'. Delete the resources associated from the page and finally you should be able to delete the RG
[image]